# javascript how to change the color of links onmouseover table cell?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I am making a navigation bar and would like the link to change color after mousover of the table cell, not the link. Is there a quick way for this? Or to get an element by its tag? (GetElementByTag("a"))

Comment: Bind a hover event to the table cell (`td`) and then look at its children for the link.

Comment: You can also do this with CSS, e.g. `td:hover a {color: purple}`

Comment: I would recommend CSS over JS for this as Stuart says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Stuart said, add the following to your css, and make sure your css is included in your html.

```
td:hover a {
  color: blue
}
```